# phpmyadmin cannot delete user

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, user-management

After upgrading to Debian Stretch phpmyadmin no longer give me the option in the User accounts tab to delete database users. Mariadb and phpmyadmin was installed with standard Debian packages and I access phpmyadmin with and administrative user that I think received the necessary privileges. The only option available is export which I hereby use:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*my_password_hash' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Did something change in phpmyadmin, no longer showing or allowing this? Is there another privilege or mariadb setting that I should change?

Answer (score 8):

Sorry, I'm getting older. It is there further down under "Add user account"!

[image: PhpMyAdmin how to remove user accounts]

Comment: I also had the same issue, I blame bad UI design.

Comment: a terrible one I shoudl say

Answer (score 3):

For those even older and more blind, like me, it's the 'go' button on the right, under 'Remove selected user accounts'